# How do I pass variables between dialplan and agi script in asterisk

Tags: asterisk, telephony, ivr, agi

I want to be able to pass the extension entered by a caller to the agi script and after it is manupulate I would like the agi script to send the result back to the dial plan as a variable. Can anyone give me an example of how to achive this in any dialplan language

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Asterisk dialplan (extensions.conf) to enter AGI, then getting the extension is possible using the ${EXTEN} channel variable.  To return information to the dialplan you can set any channel variable, though take some care to avoid channel variables that are used by Asterisk itself.

Here's a quick example using [Adhearsion](http://adhearsion.com):

In Asterisk extensions.conf:

```
exten => s,1,Background(enter-your-extension-now)
exten => _X.,1,AGI(agi://localhost/stuff)
exten => _X.,n,NoOp(Returned new extension: ${NewExten})
```

In Adhearsion's dialplan.rb:

```
stuff {
  exten = get_variable('EXTEN')
  # Do stuff to figure out what the new extension should be
  newexten = '12345'
  set_variable('NewExten', newexten)
}
```

The above code will set the ${NewExten} channel variable to "12345" and write it to the Asterisk console.